# Automatic creation of Map from defines

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I handle a library (visa) which is written in C and presents a large amount of predefined attributes as follow :

```
#define VI_ATTR_RSRC_CLASS                    (0xBFFF0001UL)
#define VI_ATTR_RSRC_NAME                     (0xBFFF0002UL)
#define VI_ATTR_RSRC_IMPL_VERSION             (0x3FFF0003UL)
#define VI_ATTR_RSRC_LOCK_STATE               (0x3FFF0004UL)
...
```

I would like to create a comprehensible map of these attributes in order to use them dynamically.
For the moment I use external script to parse the defines and create the following map :

```
std::map<ViAttr,std::string> map
{
  {VI_ATTR_RSRC_CLASS,        "VI_ATTR_RSRC_CLASS"},
  {VI_ATTR_RSRC_NAME,         "VI_ATTR_RSRC_NAME"},
  {VI_ATTR_RSRC_IMPL_VERSION, "VI_ATTR_RSRC_IMPL_VERSION"},
  {VI_ATTR_RSRC_LOCK_STATE,   "VI_ATTR_RSRC_LOCK_STATE"},
  {VI_ATTR_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH,  "VI_ATTR_MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH"},
  {VI_ATTR_USER_DATA_32,      "VI_ATTR_USER_DATA_32"},
  {VI_ATTR_FDC_CHNL,          "VI_ATTR_FDC_CHNL"},
  {VI_ATTR_FDC_MODE,          "VI_ATTR_FDC_MODE"},
  {VI_ATTR_FDC_GEN_SIGNAL_EN, "VI_ATTR_FDC_GEN_SIGNAL_EN"},
  {VI_ATTR_FDC_USE_PAIR,      "VI_ATTR_FDC_USE_PAIR"},
  {VI_ATTR_SEND_END_EN,       "VI_ATTR_SEND_END_EN"},
  {VI_ATTR_TERMCHAR,          "VI_ATTR_TERMCHAR"},
  {VI_ATTR_TMO_VALUE,         "VI_ATTR_TMO_VALUE"},
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to do this with macro ?

Comment: You can use a macro to have `M(VI_ATTR_RSRC_CLASS)` expanded to `{VI_ATTR_RSRC_CLASS,        "VI_ATTR_RSRC_CLASS"}`, etc., but the preprocessor won't be very helpful in generating the list from the previously made defines. You might as well stick to the script you already have.

Comment: ok, I was wondering if there was a way to get a list of all the existing defines, if so i could parse the list and create the map.

Comment: That you often can do. E.g., with  gcc/clang, you can do something like `gcc -E -include yourheader.h -xc /dev/null -dM`  to output just the defines that can be found inside of `yourheader.h`.